# Tapping "back" taking me too far back

Tags: bug, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Filter on tags
2. Type a tag
3. Select a tag
4. Choose a question
5. Tap back in menu bar

This takes me back to the tag filtering page instead of the filtered question page.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: HUAWEI
- Device Model: HUAWEI P7-L10

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (C900B852)